# Double square brackets in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, square-bracket

Given the following code:

```
def map(char, charmap)
    unless map = charmap[[char]]
     unless map = charmap[[char, c = input.getc]]
       input.ungetc(c) if c
       map = ''
     end
    end
  map
end
```

What is the double square brackets doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is application of the method `[]` taking an array as the argument.

Since the OP did not make clear, we cannot tell what `charmap` is, but for example if it were a hash, then `charmap[[char, c = input.getc]]` would return the value in `charmap` that corresponds to the key `[char, input.getc]`.

Comment: if I try to do something like: `charmap = [ [ 1 ] ]; puts charmap[[1]];` it does not work.

Comment: An array cannot take an array as an index, so it indeed would not work.