# Brackets [...] method taking an array as the argument

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I read in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361770/double-square-brackets-in-ruby) that the `[]` method can take an array as an argument.

Both the examples given in the linked post don't illustrate what the actual result is from using this technique.

I tried some examples which also don't provide much information:

```
[11] pry(main)> a = %w( foo bar baz )
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
[12] pry(main)> a[[1,2]]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer
from (pry):11:in '[]'
[13] pry(main)> a[['foo', 'bar']]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer
from (pry):12:in '[]'
[14] pry(main)> b = { foo: 42, bar: "dolphins", baz: "towels" }
=> {:foo=>42, :bar=>"dolphins", :baz=>"towels"}
[15] pry(main)> b[[:foo, :bar]]
=> nil
[16] pry(main)> b[["dolphins"]]
=> nil
```

What does it mean for the `[]` to take an array as an argument? What context is this technique used?

Would appreciate some runnable examples that will help me understand why all my examples return either `nil` or an error.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 how this might be a duplicate of the question, that **is linked in the very first sentence**?!

Comment: @mu-is-too-short the question which is now marked as duplicate is **linked in the very first sentence**.

Comment: @mudasobwa despite the link appearing in the question I still thought it a duplicate. But I guess I have been overruled by the Community, which is fair enough.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 you have been overruled by me personally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is just another method.

Unlike other languages, Ruby operators are just method and any method can take any object as argument, including an array.

```
class A
  def [](key)
    p key
  end
  def example(key)
    p key
  end 
end
```

And then

```
a = A.new

a[1] # => 1
a[[1, 2, 3]] # => [1, 2, 3]

a.[](1) # => 1
a.[]([1, 2, 3]) # => [1, 2, 3]

a.example(1) # => 1
a.example([1, 2, 3]) # =>  [1, 2, 3]

a.send(:'[]', 1) # => 1
a.send(:'[]', [1, 2, 3]) # => [1, 2, 3]

a.send(:example, 1) # => 1
a.send(:example, [1, 2, 3]) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Other operator methods in Ruby are

- `def []=(key, value)`
- `def +(other)`
- `def -(other)`
- `def *(other)`
- `def /(other)`
- `def %(other)`
- `def &(other)`
- `def |(other)`
- `def ^(other)`
- `def ~(other)`
- `def ==(other)`
- `def ===(other)`
- `def <=>(other)`
- `def <=(other)`
- `def >=(other)`
- `def <(other)`
- `def >(other)`
- `def <<(other)`
- `def !`
- `def ~`
- `def +@` as in `+a`
- `def -@` as in `-a`

Answer (score 0):

If it is a hash you can have the key be an array.  So you can look up via that.  In your examples you are trying to do something similar on `b` but it has no matching keys to your array param.

```
foo = {['bar'] => 'value'}
foo[['bar']]
   => "value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off @Jared's answer, the important point is a hash's key can be an array. Another way to say this is a hash's `[]` method can take an array as an argument.

Also from another perspective: an array's index cannot be an array. Another way to say this is an array's `[]` method cannot take an array as an argument.

Now the examples above make sense.

```
[11] pry(main)> a = %w( foo bar baz )
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
[12] pry(main)> a[[1,2]]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer
from (pry):11:in `[]'
[13] pry(main)> a[['foo', 'bar']]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer
from (pry):12:in `[]'
```

As mentioned above, this is an error because an array takes an integer as an index, not an array.

```
[14] pry(main)> b = { foo: 42, bar: "dolphins", baz: "towels" }
=> {:foo=>42, :bar=>"dolphins", :baz=>"towels"}
[15] pry(main)> b[[:foo, :bar]]
=> nil
[16] pry(main)> b[["dolphins"]]
=> nil
```

This isn't an error because a hash's key can be an array. However, the keys `[:foo, :bar]` and `["dolphins"]` haven't been defined so they return `nil`

Another more illustrative example is:

```
[1] pry(main)> h = { foo: 42, bar: "cats" }
=> {:foo=>42, :bar=>"cats"}
[2] pry(main)> h[[:foo, :bar]]
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> h[[:foo, :bar]] = "dogs"
=> "dogs"
[4] pry(main)> h[[:foo, :bar]]
=> "dogs"
[5] pry(main)> h
=> {:foo=>42, :bar=>"cats", [:foo, :bar]=>"dogs"}
```

In `[3]` we define the key `[:foo, :bar]` in the hash `h` to have the value `"dogs"` so in `[4]` that's what gets returned, and in `[5]` we can see the key-value pair inside the hash.

Answer (score 0):

## Receiver is a Hash

Receiver could be a Hash, with Arrays as keys

## Splat the parameter

You could also splat the array :

```
a = %w( foo bar baz )
a[*[1,2]]
#=> ["bar", "baz"]
```

This syntax is equivalent to `a[1,2]` and means `take 2 values beginning at index 1`

## Define a custom class and [] method

You could also define a custom class and a `[]` method, accepting any object :

```
class MyObject
  def self.[](argument)
    "MyObject[] has been called with an #{argument.class}"
    # do something with argument
  end
end

puts MyObject[[1,2,3]]    #=> MyObject[] has been called with an Array
puts MyObject[Object.new] #=> MyObject[] has been called with an Object
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ruby. `Whatever#[]` is just a method. Consider `Hash` class, defining class method [`Hash#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D). It is used for constructing a `Hash` instance out of an array of 2-sized arrays:

```
Hash[[[:foo, 42]]]
#⇒ { :foo => 42 }
```

Also, `Hash` itself might have arrays as keys:

```
hash = { [1, 2, 3] => :foo }
hash[[1, 2, 3]]
#⇒ :foo
```